# How to get rid of bright border around plot in `theme_bw` transparent mode?

Tags: r, ggplot2, printing

Is there a way to get rid of these white lines in `theme_bw()` when printed transparent onto darker background? In `theme_minimal()` they don't appear, but I want `theme_bw()`. I tried several `theme()` options to modify, without success though.

*Example:*

```
data(iris)
names(iris) <- tolower(names(iris))

library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background= element_blank())
pdf("plot1.pdf", width=4, height=4)
plot1
dev.off()

plot2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background= element_blank())
pdf("plot2.pdf", width=4, height=4)
plot2
dev.off()
```

[image]

**Note:** I'm doing this in InDesign CS4.

Comment: How did you create the blue background? Or its just for illustration? My plots/pdfs are totally white, without any visible border.

Comment: What about `panel.border=element_rect(fill="transparent")` ?

Comment: @SeGa The "friends" are still there. I'm doing this in InDesign, placing the pdfs onto this blue background.

Comment: What you're looking for is `plot.background`, not `panel.background`. Plot is the area *outside* the axes. So try `plot.background = element_blank()`

Comment: @camille GREAT, that solved it, case you want to make an answer out of it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `plot.background` theme element, not the `panel.background` one. The plot is the entire area, including outside the axes, while the panel is the area inside or between the axes.

Ugly plots to illustrate the difference:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background= element_rect(color = "red", fill = "yellow", size = 6))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(color = "red", fill = "yellow", size = 6))
```

[image]

`theme_bw` defaults to a plot background with a white border.

```r
theme_bw()$plot.background
List of 5
 $ fill         : NULL
 $ colour       : chr "white"
 $ size         : NULL
 $ linetype     : NULL
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_rect" "element"
```

So you can instead set `plot.background` to an `element_blank`, or an `element_rect` with a color of `NA` or transparent, or any other means of making it invisible. Since you don't need any attributes of the plot background, the easiest is just `plot.background = element_blank()`.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Panel Border should does the trick

```
plot1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background= element_blank())
```

Comment: Nope, it does not, this removes the axes.

Comment: Sorry, I  guess I'm unable to reproduce... I do not see that border.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `theme_minimal` and adapt the theme?

```
col = "#383838"
plot2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=sepal.length, y=sepal.width)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(rect=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = col),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = col, color = col, size = 0.1),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = col),
        panel.background= element_blank())
pdf("plot2.pdf", width=4, height=4)
plot2
dev.off()
```

Or do you have to use `theme_bw` for some reason?